# how can i find the neighbours from the given list?

Tags: python, graph-algorithm, nearest-neighbor

```
from, to
0, 1
1, 2
2, 3
3, 4
4, 0 
4, 1
5, 3
```

I have an edge list (made of two node lists) which shown above which is given in a text FILE.How can i find the neighbors of each node and output can be shown as [[1, 4], [0, 2, 4], [1, 3], [2, 4, 5], [0, 1, 3], [3]]
so [1,4] are the neighbors for 0, and [0,2,4] are neighbors for 1 and so on

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's not obvious what you want, what you have and how you expect to get there with what you've done. Please *explain* what you've been trying to do to achieve this and give more detail about the task you're trying to solve.

Comment: Guys, it's a list of neighbour pairs. What isn't clear? There is no 3, 1 or 1, 3 on that list.

Comment: You are not clear with what you want and how you want it to be.

Comment: What do any of the tags in your question have to do with the problem? Is there something network-related or cvs-related here that isn't obvious that would help us understand? If not, just adding random tags doesn't help you get more answers, it just helps you get more downvotes from people who are experts in some domain that's irrelevant to your problem and can't possibly help but can find your question useless or even annoying.

Comment: so if 0,1 means 0 and 1 are connected and so 4,0 means 0 and 4 is connected so 1,4 is a neighbour of 0

Comment: sorry im kind of new to the website, so i have a csv file which contains the coordinates of nodes

Comment: Now tell us how you are deciding that 0 and 1 are connected or not ? By that list ?

Comment: so far i have written the program to find the coordinates of the nodes(the data of which i have statated)

Comment: yes 0 and 1 are connected by that list, so is 2,3

Comment: def read_graph_from_file(filename):
    my_file=open(filename,"rU")
    position_list=[]

    for row in my_file:
        value=row[:-1]
        my_list=value.split(",")

        try:
            if my_list[2] != "":
                node = my_list[0]
                positionX = my_list[1]
                positionY = my_list[2]
                position_list = tuple([positionX,positionY])
        except IndexError:
            pass

Answer (score 2):

```
import collections

d = collections.defaultdict(set)
with open('filename') as f:
    for line in f:
        x, y = map(int, line.rstrip().split(", "))
        d[x].add(y)
        d[y].add(x)

#defaultdict(<type 'set'>, {0: set([1, 4]), 1: set([0, 2, 4]), 2: set([1, 3]), 3: set([2, 4, 5]), 4: set([0, 1, 3]), 5: set([3])})
```

Comment: Most straightforward solution. Also nice of you to show how to read the data from the OP's text file.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = [ 0,1,2,3,4,4,5]
y = [ 1,2,3,4,0,1,3]
```

**Option 1:**

```
l1 = [(x[i] , y[i]) for i in range(len(x))]
l2 = [(y[i] , x[i]) for i in range(len(x))]
l1.extend(l2)

[[l[0] for l in l1 if l[1] == j] for j in range(5)]
```

**Option 2:**

use a dictionary:

```
for i in range(len(x)):
  if not d.has_key(x[i]):
    d[x[i]] = []
  d[x[i]].append(y[i])
  if not d.has_key(y[i]):
    d[y[i]] = []
  d[y[i]].append(x[i])


print d
```

Comment: `has_key` has been deprecated for a long time now - the new syntax is "if key in dict".  Or better, use a defaultdict like @KarolyHorvath